# How to calculate total amount of products sold per year?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

1. products (it has product id, price etc.)
2. orders (it has order id, date etc.)
3. orders_products (it has orders detail like product quantity etc.)

I want to calculate total amount of products sold per year. To achieve this, I wrote following query:

```
SELECT YEAR(`o`.`date_purchased`) AS year,
       SUM(`op`.`products_quantity`) AS TotalUnits,
       `p`.`products_id`,
       `p`.`products_price` AS price,
       ( SUM(`op`.`products_quantity`) * `p`.`products_price` ) AS TotalAmount
FROM   `orders` AS `o`
       INNER JOIN `orders_products` AS `op`
               ON `o`.`orders_id` = `op`.`orders_id`
       INNER JOIN `products` AS `p`
               ON `op`.`products_id` = `p`.`products_id`
GROUP  BY `p`.`products_id`
ORDER  BY year
```

It gives me following result set:

[image]

It gives me total amount grouped by product. But I want to get total amount grouped by year instead.

So for year 2016 (and for other years too), I want following result:

```
2016     10,606 (since 6478 + 632 + 2072 + 1424)
```

But I can't calculate total amount grouped by year because each product has a different price. So how can I modify my existing query to get total amount of products sold per year?

If it can't be achieved by MySQL alone, then I will not hesitate to use PHP.

Comment: add GROUP  BY YEAR(`o`.`date_purchased`), `p`.`products_id`

Comment: For next time, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Kinjal, wrong solution provided by you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to bring the multiplication of quantity and price into the `SUM` so that each product's quantity is multiplied by its own price:

```
SELECT YEAR(`o`.`date_purchased`) AS year,
       SUM(`op`.`products_quantity`) AS TotalUnits,
       SUM(`op`.`products_quantity` * `p`.`products_price`) AS TotalAmount
FROM   `orders` AS `o`
INNER JOIN `orders_products` AS `op` ON `o`.`orders_id` = `op`.`orders_id`
INNER JOIN `products` AS `p` ON `op`.`products_id` = `p`.`products_id`
GROUP  BY year
ORDER  BY year
```

Comment: well there's no `GROUP` in sql, only `GROUP BY`

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ We all make little typos occasionally (well, at least I do)... thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Nick, Absolutely great! Your solution provided me the exact result what I was looking for. This was the key point `SUM(op.products_quantity * p.products_price) AS TotalAmount`. However there was a typo `GROUP`. And of course! alias is supported in my mysql.

Comment: Yes, @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ just pointed the typo out. Somehow I managed to delete the `BY` when I cut and pasted your query. Sorry...

Comment: @Nick, ok, now i can delete my answer.